# Opened applicatons icons on system tray

Tags: wingpanel, user-interface

Is there a possibility to enable opened applications icons to display on wingpanel tray? Now not even one application is being showed. I have elementary OS 5.1.2 Hera. And my system tray with opened few applications looks like that [image: wingpanel]

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by installing [Namarupa](https://github.com/donadigo/wingpanel-indicator-namarupa)

[image]

Hat tip to Anderson Laverde from the ElementaryOS Slack Channel